# Session State Error only when using FQDN

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

I'm using session state variables in my webpart on SharePoint Foundation 2010. It works fine until a user accesses the web application using the FQDN.

`http://myapp` = works fine
`http://myapp.company.com` = error

It gives Session State errors. When I try to edit the page and add the webpart in the `myapp.company.com` it gives me the below error, but the `/myapp` page works properly.

[image: Session State Error]

I've made the changes to the web.config on every server on the farm and session state **DOES** work so long as the FQDN is not used.

FQDN error:

> Error:   Unexpected  System.Web.HttpException: Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the `<configuration>\<system.web>`

Comment: did you enable the session state in the IIS as well for the web app?

Answer (score 1):

When IIS is not configured properly after creating SharePoint application and there are web parts or features that use session you may get same error as you mentioned.

Solution
As a solution you must register session state handler module in IIS.

1. Open Internet Information Services manager.
2. Move to site where problem occurred.
3. Open modules list of this site.
4. Add session state handler like show on the following image (click on
   it):
   [image]
5. Click OK, recycle application pool and refresh the page.

I am not very sure why SharePoint doesn’t enable this module by default as mostly default session state module is enough.

Comment: I checked and Session State was already running in the modules on all servers, and the site on each server.

Comment: try this one http://geekswithblogs.net/intermark/archive/2009/09/06/hellipsession-state-can-only-be-used-when-enablesessionstate-is-set.aspx

Comment: also what is your AAM? which URL in default zone?

Comment: also share the web.config's line for session state.

Comment: I tried the first link on my local machine, but those options were already checked.

Comment: The address without the FQDN is in the default. The FQDN address is in the intranet.

Comment: try to swap the url and see if works now other way...

Comment: <pages enableSessionState="true" enableViewState="true" enableViewStateMac="true" validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPPageParserFilter, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" asyncTimeout="7">

Comment: <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">

 <remove name="Session" />

   <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition="" />

Comment: I swapped them (intranet and default) and still the same result in the logs:  Unexpected System.Web.HttpException: Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true

Comment: how many servers in the farm?

Comment: 3 - An application server and two web servers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15184/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mcse-and-jarthur).